# How to refer primary key as Foreign to various table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table called User Which contain user_id as primary key 
I have other tables like Doctor ,patient,staff ...etc which contain column called created by which reffer to user_id of user table.

Here is my issue I cannot use same constrain name across different table for example

```
ALTER TABLE `emr@default`.`staff` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_created_by`
  FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
  REFERENCES `emr@default`.`users` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

is created successfully

when I try with other table

```
ALTER TABLE `emr@default`.patient 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_created_by`
  FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
  REFERENCES `emr@default`.`users` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

generating error Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-1_7a64'

if I try

```
ALTER TABLE `emr@default`.patient 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_created_by1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
  REFERENCES `emr@default`.`users` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

is creating fk

my Doubt is can we use same constrain name.if not can I create different constrain name that will not effect anythin

Comment: 'can we use same constrain name' - no has to unique in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint names can have conflicts between tables.  That is why I include both the table and column names in the constraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE `emr@default`.patient 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_patient_created_by`
  FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
  REFERENCES `emr@default`.`users` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `emr@default`.`staff` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_staff_created_by`
  FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
  REFERENCES `emr@default`.`users` (`user_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```